# Find string and replace each occurance with different string

Tags: list, batch-file, replace

I am looking for a simple batch solution for the following:

In a number of files I want to replace a string with another one. Can do this with Notepad++. However, each new string has to be unique, read from a list of new strings.

So, if 'abc' occurs in some files, and I have a list with new strings, replace it this way:

abc  -->  alex
abc  -->  ben
abc  -->  chris
abc  -->  dave
etc.

I can have a txt file with the new strings to read from.

Hope someone has a solution for me!

Many thanks,
Lennart

Comment: A *simple* batch solution for such a problem? Hardly possible. However, in the end it may just depend on what you find simple.

Comment: @Andriy: Only if your definition of "batch" is ".bat file"...

Answer (score 2):

Would a Perl script work?

```
my @words = qw(alex ben chris dave ...);

while (<>) {
    s/abc/shift @words/ge;
    print;
}
```

If you want the word list to loop:

```
my @words = qw(...);
my $i = 0;

while (<>) {
    # I know I should have written this in a more readable way...
    s{abc}{$words[$i++] // $words[$i=0]}ge;
    print;
}
```

Comment: In `s/x/y/z`, *`x`* is a regexp, *`y`* is the replacement text, and *`z`* are flags. If the "`e`" flag is specified, then replacement text is treated as executable Perl code.

Answer (score 1):

Or as batch script

```
@echo off
setlocal Disabledelayedexpansion
set "wordlist=alex ben chris dave"
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (myFile.txt) do (
    set "line=%%a"
    setlocal Enabledelayedexpansion
    for /F "tokens=1,*" %%b in ("!wordlist!") do (
        set "newline=!line:abc=%%b!"
        (echo(!newline!)
        if !newline! NEQ !line! (
            endlocal
            set "wordlist=%%c"
        ) ELSE ( 
            endlocal 
        )
    )   
)
```

**Edit** Change to a "!" safe variant

Comment: Unfortunately, delayed expansion happens even in `set "line=%%a"`, causing everything that looks like a `!variable!` in source text to be expanded. (Moving `setlocal` inside the outer `for` loop seems to fix it.)

Comment: @grawity: Ok you got me, I only shows a simple solution, not a perfect one, the perfect one is much more complicated

Answer (score 0):

Try and find a `sed` executable for Windows which supports the `-i` (`--inline`) switch and your job will become a toddler's task!